# Location of Zeros of a Complex Polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is how to approach the following problem:

> How many zeros does $p(z)=z^5+5z+1$ have in:
>   $$\begin{array}{}
> (a)&\:|z|\leq1.\\
> (b)&\:|z|\leq2.\\
> (c)&\:1<|z|<2.
> \end{array}$$

I'm really unsure how to approach the problem. If possible, I'd prefer just a hint so I can solve the problem on my own, but I understand if the problem is too easy and makes it difficult to offer a good hint without giving the solution away. Thanks!

Comment: [Rouché's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) would probably be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: use Rouche's Theorem and

$$(a)\;\;\;f(z):=z^5+1\;,\;\;g(z):=5z\Longrightarrow |f(z)|<|g(z)|\,\,\text{ for}\,\,|z|=1\ldots$$

$$(b)\;\;\;f(z)=5z+1\;,\;\;g(z)=z^5\Longrightarrow |f(z)|<|g(z)|\,\,\text{for}\,\,|z|=2\ldots$$

For (c) you only need to think a little about the above...

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure....